# Non-Image Bar Codes for Django

Tags: python, django, barcode

I was wondering if there's a library that I can use to create bar codes in Django using just HTML + CSS rather than producing the bar codes as images (like in **reportlab** & **pybarcode**). I'm reluctant to use images because I'm creating many bar codes on the same page and I feel images could be a little slow.

P.S *This technique has been used by  [dinesh/barcode](https://github.com/milon/barcode) as a laravel library in php*

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use [jquery-barcode](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Based-Barcode-Generator-Barcode.html) which is completely works at client end